# Unable to set path for nodejs

Tags: node.js

When I try to check the version of nodejs by running he command in my terminal "node -v" its shows 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I tried to set the path but the nodejs folder is not in my pc. Please help me out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4BOo.png)

Comment: after installation of node js , it will set path in Environment variables , you have to restart your pc and check , node -v is working or not

Comment: I suggest u to reinstall node. This link may help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: Please consider adding more info like which os are you on? how did you install? what is the version?